# Find all occurrences of JSON element using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

How can you parse out all the values for a particular data point within a complex json response form a rest service call?

Here is my JQUERY code to get the rest service json response. I am looking to get all occurrences of "Id" for all "Approver" elements found in the json data and add them to delimited list - preferably using a

> ;

to separate each "Id"

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script><script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("button").click(function(){

    $.ajax({ 
        type: 'GET', 
        url: 'MySite/Change/Request/12345/Approvals/GetApprovalGroupUsers?changeNumber=98765', 

        data: { get_param: 'value' }, 
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) { 

            $.each(data, function(index, element) {
                $('body').append($('<div>', {
                    text: element.Id
                }));
            });
        }
    });

        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<button>Click me to get listing of Id's</button>
</body>
</html>
```

The json data from the service in such:

```
{
    "ApprovalSession": "3ebd4e73-7fc5-4113-9ccd-18833318ee09",
    "LoadStatus": 0,
    "Index": 0,
    "ApprovalId": 0,
    "Type": null,
    "Approver": null,
    "ApproverDisplay": null,
    "Status": null,
    "CreatedBy": null,
    "CanBeRemoved": false,
    "ConfigurationItems": [
        "cigs01e4a002( OPERATING SYSTEM )",
        "cigs01e4a002( OPERATING SYSTEM )",
        "cigs01e4a004( OPERATING SYSTEM )",
        "cigs01e4a004( OPERATING SYSTEM )"
    ],
    "ApprovalReasons": [
        {
            "AssociatedCI": "abc4a002( OPERATING SYSTEM )",
            "AssociatedRuleName": "Default Impact",
            "AssociatedRuleApprovalType": null,
            "AssociatedRulePartyType": "Targeted Group",
            "AssociatedRulePartyName": "Operational Owner",
            "AssociatedAdditionalComment": ""
        },
        {
            "AssociatedCI": "xyza004( OPERATING SYSTEM )",
            "AssociatedRuleName": "Default Impact ",
            "AssociatedRuleApprovalType": null,
            "AssociatedRulePartyType": "Targeted Group",
            "AssociatedRulePartyName": "Technical Owner",
            "AssociatedAdditionalComment": "Substitute Role"
        }
    ],
    "PossibleApprovers": [
        {
            "Approver": {
                "Id": "Vzz436",
                "Display": "some name",
                "LineOfBusinessCode": "25",
                "LineOfBusinessName": "Unix",
                "LineOfBusinessHierarchy": null,
                "PhoneNumber": "+123456789",
                "RoleName": null,
                "FullName": null,
                "LineOfBusiness": null,
                "ErrorMessage": null
            },
            "IsEscalation": false,
            "IsDelegate": false
        },
        {
            "Approver": {
                "Id": "ppp71",
                "Display": "more names",
                "LineOfBusinessCode": "5",
                "LineOfBusinessName": "Tech",
                "LineOfBusinessHierarchy": null,
                "PhoneNumber": "+987654321",
                "RoleName": null,
                "FullName": null,
                "LineOfBusiness": null,
                "ErrorMessage": null
            },
            "IsEscalation": false,
            "IsDelegate": false
        },
        {
            "Approver": {
                "Id": "aaa5",
                "Display": "mickey mouse",
                "LineOfBusinessCode": "8",
                "LineOfBusinessName": "Digital",
                "LineOfBusinessHierarchy": null,
                "PhoneNumber": "+87877676665",
                "RoleName": null,
                "FullName": null,
                "LineOfBusiness": null,
                "ErrorMessage": null
            },
            "IsEscalation": false,
            "IsDelegate": false
        }
    ],
    "OriginalApprovals": [ ],
    "AggregatedApproval": null,
    "IsAggregated": false,
    "AggregationId": 0,
    "UpdatedBy": null,
    "UpdatedDt": null,
    "IsGroupActive": false

}
```

Comment: why down vote a question without expressing why or adding something meaningful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can get all ID's of the approvers, delimited by a semi-colon.

```js
var data = {
    "ApprovalSession": "3ebd4e73-7fc5-4113-9ccd-18833318ee09",
    "LoadStatus": 0,
    "Index": 0,
    "ApprovalId": 0,
    "Type": null,
    "Approver": null,
    "ApproverDisplay": null,
    "Status": null,
    "CreatedBy": null,
    "CanBeRemoved": false,
    "ConfigurationItems": [
        "cigs01e4a002( OPERATING SYSTEM )",
        "cigs01e4a002( OPERATING SYSTEM )",
        "cigs01e4a004( OPERATING SYSTEM )",
        "cigs01e4a004( OPERATING SYSTEM )"
    ],
    "ApprovalReasons": [
        {
            "AssociatedCI": "abc4a002( OPERATING SYSTEM )",
            "AssociatedRuleName": "Default Impact",
            "AssociatedRuleApprovalType": null,
            "AssociatedRulePartyType": "Targeted Group",
            "AssociatedRulePartyName": "Operational Owner",
            "AssociatedAdditionalComment": ""
        },
        {
            "AssociatedCI": "xyza004( OPERATING SYSTEM )",
            "AssociatedRuleName": "Default Impact ",
            "AssociatedRuleApprovalType": null,
            "AssociatedRulePartyType": "Targeted Group",
            "AssociatedRulePartyName": "Technical Owner",
            "AssociatedAdditionalComment": "Substitute Role"
        }
    ],
    "PossibleApprovers": [
        {
            "Approver": {
                "Id": "Vzz436",
                "Display": "some name",
                "LineOfBusinessCode": "25",
                "LineOfBusinessName": "Unix",
                "LineOfBusinessHierarchy": null,
                "PhoneNumber": "+123456789",
                "RoleName": null,
                "FullName": null,
                "LineOfBusiness": null,
                "ErrorMessage": null
            },
            "IsEscalation": false,
            "IsDelegate": false
        },
        {
            "Approver": {
                "Id": "ppp71",
                "Display": "more names",
                "LineOfBusinessCode": "5",
                "LineOfBusinessName": "Tech",
                "LineOfBusinessHierarchy": null,
                "PhoneNumber": "+987654321",
                "RoleName": null,
                "FullName": null,
                "LineOfBusiness": null,
                "ErrorMessage": null
            },
            "IsEscalation": false,
            "IsDelegate": false
        },
        {
            "Approver": {
                "Id": "aaa5",
                "Display": "mickey mouse",
                "LineOfBusinessCode": "8",
                "LineOfBusinessName": "Digital",
                "LineOfBusinessHierarchy": null,
                "PhoneNumber": "+87877676665",
                "RoleName": null,
                "FullName": null,
                "LineOfBusiness": null,
                "ErrorMessage": null
            },
            "IsEscalation": false,
            "IsDelegate": false
        }
    ],
    "OriginalApprovals": [ ],
    "AggregatedApproval": null,
    "IsAggregated": false,
    "AggregationId": 0,
    "UpdatedBy": null,
    "UpdatedDt": null,
    "IsGroupActive": false

}

data.PossibleApprovers.forEach(function (approver) { document.write(approver.Approver.Id + ';')})
```